# Magento 2.4.5 layered navigation filter not working after upgrade 2.4.3 to 2.4.5

Tags: magento2.4.5

I've tried reindexing, updating the products, setup:upgrade, etc and none of this seems to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue has already been resolved in Magento 2.4-develop branch. To apply the fix, apply this patch:
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/a9170022cce29993e586ffaa6f4c1cc357ee3b11.diff

Related commit: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/a9170022cce29993e586ffaa6f4c1cc357ee3b11

Related pull request: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/35986/

There is another issue: the number of total items in the toolbar is incorrect. Magento (Adobe) has published a patch for this issue:
[ACSD-48234: catalog search result shows incorrect category item count Display Out of Stock Products enabled](https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/support-tools/patches/v1-1-25/acsd-48234-catalog-search-result-shows-incorrect-category-item-count-when-show-out-of-stock-option-enabled.html?lang=en) https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-knowledge-base/kb/support-tools/patches/v1-1-25/acsd-48234-catalog-search-result-shows-incorrect-category-item-count-when-show-out-of-stock-option-enabled.html?lang=en

You can apply it via the Quality Patches Tool (QPT) or via composer patch file:
https://github.com/magento/quality-patches/tree/master/patches/os
searching for "ACSD-48234"

Comment: Thank you for the solution.
But I have changed in vendor/magento/module-elasticsearch/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection/SearchResultApplier.php and it is working fine.
Can you let me know how to I override this file?

Thank you

Comment: I tried like this /app/code/Magento/Elasticsearch/Model/ResourceModel/Fulltext/Collection/SearchResultApplier.php but not working.

Comment: I strongly recommend you apply this patch via composer. Here is the document from Magento: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/upgrade-guide/patches/apply.html
If you need help, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Thank you :)
It is working fine.

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 3):

**Solutions**

**1. Total count in the toolbar is wrong**

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/362881/1883

Create a patch to disable the `update_toolbar_count` plugin.

Core file: `vendor/magento/module-inventory-catalog/etc/di.xml`

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar">
    <plugin 
        name="update_toolbar_count" 
        type="Magento\InventoryCatalog\Plugin\Catalog\Block\ProductList\UpdateToolbarCount" 
        disabled="true" />
</type>
```

**2. Show per page dropdown not working**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74828487/327862

Create a patch

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/toolbar/limiter.phtml`

```
            <?php if ($block->isLimitCurrent($_key)):?>
                selected="selected"
            <?php endif ?>>
-           <?= $block->escapeHtml($localeFormatter->formatNumber((int) $_limit)) ?>
+           <?= $block->escapeHtml(
+               is_numeric($_limit) ? $localeFormatter->formatNumber((int) $_limit) : $_limit
+           ) ?>
        </option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

Ref: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/bb55549cd3016987663272e7ffe3f452c8d6e40d